# How to sort nested dictionary inside a list?

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

```
data = [{'USA': [{'accommodations': '2 BR ','Price': 1245},
                 {'accommodations': '5 BR ','Price': 1045}]},
        {'Dubai': [{'accommodations': '2 BR | Sleeps 6','Price': 966},
                   {'accommodations': '5 BR | Sleeps 6','Price': 800}]}]
```

I want to sort above data on the basis of Price.

I know I have to do something like this, but I am confused because of nested dictionary and list.

```
 sorted(data, key=lambda k: k["Price"])
```

Also, wants an only first (i.e. minimum) value entry of a sorted list.

Expected output:

```
data = [{'usa': {'accommodations': '5 BR ','Price': 1045}},
        {'Dubai':{'accommodations': '5 BR | Sleeps 6','Price': 800}}]
```

Comment: So, yes, there are *two* `Price` for each entry, so what do you want to sort by…?

Comment: First value entry of sorted list. So you want the minimum?

Comment: Yes, I want the minimum Price value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to fairly complex data nature, you could use a *dict comprehension* (where only the lowest (based on its price) accommodation is kept for each country), inside a *list comprehension* (that iterates through all the countries):

> ```
> >>> [{k: min(v, key=lambda x: x["Price"]) for k, v in item.items()} for item in data]
> [{'USA': {'accommodations': '5 BR ', 'Price': 1045}}, {'Dubai': {'accommodations': '5 BR | Sleeps 6', 'Price': 800}}]
> ```

**Resources**:

- [[Python]: PEP 274 -- Dict Comprehensions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274)
- [[Python]: List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)
- [[Python]: **min**(*iterable, *[, key, default]*)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min)

Answer (score 1):

This is one way using list comprehensions. Since your dictionaries contain one item each, we extract the first key and first value. Alternatively, you could use `next(iter(d.keys()))` / `next(iter(d.values()))`.

```
from operator import itemgetter

# sort increasing by price
res = [{list(item.keys())[0]: sorted(list(item.values())[0], key=itemgetter('Price'))}
       for item in data]

# get lowest price
res = [{list(item.keys())[0]: min(list(item.values())[0], key=itemgetter('Price'))}
       for item in data]

print(res)

[{'USA': {'accommodations': '5 BR ', 'Price': 1045}},
 {'Dubai': {'accommodations': '5 BR | Sleeps 6', 'Price': 800}}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `min`:

```
data = [{'USA': [{'accommodations': '2 BR ','Price': 1245},
             {'accommodations': '5 BR ','Price': 1045}]},
    {'Dubai': [{'accommodations': '2 BR | Sleeps 6','Price': 966},
               {'accommodations': '5 BR | Sleeps 6','Price': 800}]}]
final_data = [{a:min(b, key=lambda x:x['Price']) for a, b in i.items()} for i in data]
```

Output:

```
[{'Usa': {'accommodations': '5 BR ', 'Price': 1045}}, {'Dubai': {'accommodations': '5 BR | Sleeps 6', 'Price': 800}}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
filteredData = []
for records in data:
    for country, accommodations in records.items():
        accommodations = sorted(accommodations, key=lambda k: k["Price"])
        filteredData.append({country:accommodations[0]})
```